# Reimplementing std::swap, should I use const for tmp variable?

Tags: c++, stl, swap

I working on reimplementing some methods from C++ STL library. And there is a question about generic swap implementation: Should I use `const` modifier for the temporary variable or not?

There is my variant:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
  const T tmp = a;
  a = b;
  b = tmp;
}
```

Update:

I checked several STL implementations; some are using const while other are not.

I think, using const may be limiting the generality of the `swap`...

I want to write portable implementation, and which is most generic (accept most classes).

Comment: NO don't use `const` because you're going to assign to a non-`const` variable anyways, so what's the point?

Comment: You might as well make it as efficient as the standard library version, which moves them into one another instead of copying. You'd also need a version for arrays.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: What is wrong with `const`? I don't see any problem. So I'm curious to know your thoughts.

Comment: chris, would you like to explain about move and efficiency of standard library version?

Comment: Do you want to be able to swap `std::auto_ptr`, and other broken classes with non-const copy constructors? You can argue the point either way - I'd choose to be liberal in what I accept.

Comment: @osgx, Imagine copying a pointer thrice instead of everything it points to thrice. That's basically what moving will buy you.

Comment: The whole point of `std::swap` is that it **isn't** called except as a last resort. Trying to optimize the "generic swap implementation" is kinda missing the entire point of that function.

Comment: @Nawaz, well nothing is wrong with `const`, but it seems silly to make it const when you're going to end up assigning it to something non-`const`.  After all, what advantages does it bring using it in this case?

Comment: @TonyTheLion: What advantages does `const` bring usually? What advantages does `non-const` bring in this case? With the advent of multithreading and asynchronous programming, I tend to use `const` religiously, as much as possible. In fact, by default I make every variable `const`, unless needed otherwise!

Comment: Mehrdad, so using sort or any other STL algo is the last resort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you should do it, and is why tmp should not be const:

```
 template<typename T>
 void swap(T& a, T& b)
 {
   T tmp = std::move(a);
   a = std::move(b);
   b = std::move(tmp);//needs to change tmp, so tmp cannot be const
 }
```

This allows for a move assignment of tmp (if possible).

However, there are a lot more nuances to this.

Comment: When the `std::move` was defined (C++1998, C++2003 or C++2011)?

Answer (score 1):

`const` is a help for writing correct programs. The compiler verifies that you don't break this contract. The author or reader knows the value because it doesn't change after initialization. In this case, the scope of the variables is so small and the function is so simple that it doesn't make a difference though. Keep it there for consistency, it won't hurt.

Comment: But is it possible to write a class, which will not be swapped by the `std::swap` with `const` modifier for tmp?

Comment: Yes, you can write one where the copy-constructor doesn't take a reference-to-const. Such a class would be special and/or broken though, so I would prefer to know of it instead of silently compiling into something senseless.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: It is possible to have uses for a class with such a copy-constructor though, isn't it? I know that `auto_ptr` is not an example of good design and good C++, but the same principle could be needed elsewhere, could it not?

Comment: auto_ptr has a feature which makes it difficult to use in some situations, the release() function returns a pointer. C++11 has unique_ptr, which is better. Apart from that, I personally find it very useful, as exclusive ownership gives interesting guarantees. The principle even applies to other resources, for example I have a similar wrapper around a win32 HANDLE for which a swap() with a const temporary would fail. OTOH, that class provides its own swap() implementation.